# How to open a window then load my XAML file to it? (XAML and C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and C# and i need some help - sorry about the newbie question!

Anyway I have a control panel 'window' as the file thats loaded when i run my project, and i then have a button on this control panel, that when clicked triggers an event.  Inside this 'event function' I am trying to load a new window that has its own XAML code behind, how do i go about doing this?  I have googled but to no avail.

Please explain in laymens terms, I am still getting the hang of this all.

Thanks!

```
private void btnCustomers_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //load in Customers.xaml file here - in a new window 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare an instance of the class that is your other window then call `Show()` on it.  So if your other window is call `MySecondWindow` you write the following in your event handler.

```
MySecondWindow otherWindow = new MySecondWindow();
otherWindow.Show();
```

A basic explination of how windows work can be found on the [MSDN Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Y1108).

Comment: Great! this is exactly what i was after.  Thanks for your help